# Extended Dismax Query parser avoid replacing multiple white spaces with single white space

Tags: solr, edismax

I am using Extended Dismax Query parser in our setup. I am running the following query to get documents related to a certain company

```
_query_:"{!edismax qf='company' q.op='OR'}(\"the procter  & gamble company\")"
```

For some issue with our indexing logic, we have multiple spaces in this company name **the procter  & gamble company**

When i run above query, it is not giving any results as edismax parser is replacing multiple white spaces with single white space. Following is the snippet from debug output

```
"rawquerystring": "_query_:\"{!edismax qf='company' q.op='OR'}(\\\"the procter  & gamble company\\\")\"",
    "querystring": "_query_:\"{!edismax qf='company' q.op='OR'}(\\\"the procter  & gamble company\\\")\"",
    "parsedquery": "(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((company:the procter & gamble company)))/no_coord",
    "parsedquery_toString": "+(company:the procter & gamble company)",
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
    "explain": {}
```

I am using filetype as **lower_string** for field **company**. The following is the definition of the analyzer.

```
<fieldType name="lower_string" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any suggestions on how can i tell edisMax parser not to replace multiple white spaces ?

Comment: This should have nothing to do with your query parser, but how your query is analyzed. Post the field type definition for the company field.

Comment: I do not think so. It is working fine when i do not use edismax query parser. However, i have updated the question with field type definition & analyzer.

Comment: I tried this out. It doesn't happen when the field is of type string. So I guess, this has something to do with a combination of the query parser and the field analyzers.